# ADS1115: Using 5V supply instead of 3V, do I need to increase the logic level signal from 3V to 5V?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, i2c, logic-level, 3.3v

I am using a microcontroller that has a 3.3V Logic level output. The microcontroller is connected to ADS1115 via I2C pins, and the ADS1115 can be powered with 3.3V or 5V depending on the range of voltage measurement.

Since I am powering ADS1115 with 5V, do I need to have a logic level translator between the the microcontroller and ADS1115? Specifically, can the ADS1115, with 5V supply, still be able to communicate with a microcontroller that has a 3.3V logic level signal?

Comment: Some MCUs have rotective diodes between PS+ and input/output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never assume. THe first place you should check for this kind of information is in the datasheet:

[image]

But you also have to pay attention to the operating conditions header under at the top of the section that the table is under:

[image]

It doesn't matter here because the voltages are listed in terms of Vdd.

But sometimes there different tables under different sections for different operating voltages.

Or sometimes there is only one section for one operating voltage even though the device can operate under multiple voltages and the table lists things in terms of straight voltages rather than Vdd. At that point you need to dig deeper.

Comment: Makes so much sense. Thank you for explaining it clearly .

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the MCU allows the I2C pins (which are open-drain) to be pulled above Vdd for the MCU. The ADS1115 needs 0.7*Vdd for a guaranteed logic high on digital inputs, which is nominally 3.5V and higher than 3.3V.

Most likely you will need voltage translators. A pair of MOSFETs and some resistors will work.